# How can I encode JS code in a Webpack/Rollup bundle to prevent modification with a simple editor?

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollup

Foreword: I know there is no silver bullet to encode/obfuscate JavaScript to prevent modification.

I use Webpack/Rollup + Gulp + React to build a `bundle.js`, and it is included in a few pages of a very large website. Everything is under a very old web-based content management system.

The `bundle.js` file includes paragraphs of text and other stuff. And source code is checked into GitHub.

There are multiple content editors in the organization and most of them are not software developers or study in CS. So they don't use GitHub and Webpack (and they don't want to use).

My problem is, sometimes, they will just open my minified `bundle.js` and modify some texts manually. So their changes only goes into CMS but not GitHub.

Out-of-sync contents makes maintaining these pages extremely difficult. I want to encode the JS file so that they are not able to modify them too easily in Notepad. Because they are not very skillful, if they can't modify it with Notepad, they won't solve it and will point it back to the correct person.

What is the best way to do so? And will the solution break source maps?

I know I might be able to do it with BASE64 encode on Gulp, and then decode on browser side. So the `bundle.js` looks garbage to most people. But is there any better solution to this?

Comment: You can't. Also you're trying to solve a people problem, stop looking for technical fixes.

Comment: I could do base64 encode during Gulp, and then on browser side, do base64 decode + eval(). It will solve the issue but I am looking for a better solution. And because editors are from different companies/departments, I can't fix people problem, too much politics to deal with.

Comment: 1. So mention that. 2. *"better"* how, precisely? 3. Then give up, and involve someone who can.

Comment: Also note that what you're doing is purposefully breaking someone else's workflow. Those people presumably have reasons and business needs for doing it. They and the people who rely on them getting it done will likely not take kindly to your spanner in their works.

Comment: Why do people who should not have access to this stuff have access to this stuff? That + solving the people problem + figuring out how to fix the actual problem those people are trying to deal with here is really how this needs to be solved; not base64 encoding.

Comment: 1. Mentioned, but no one is listening or reading BIG UPPERCASE WARNING. I hope I could secure it but everyone is admin in the old CMS. *sad* 2. I think my solution might break source map, not super important. 3. To give up, I could: a) sync their changes every time I need to modify my page, tiresome; b) not doing my complex pages in React, difficult; c) resign my job.

Comment: A good developer is a developer that can solve problems without writing a single line of code. Sounds like this is one of those times. Yes, office politics sucks… but it's part of the job, or at least should be part of *somebody's* job.

Comment: In Hong Kong, there is always somethings more urgent than urgent. If someone look at the file and they think they could change it, they change it, and WITHOUT notifying you. And it will be me to fix stuff they occasionally break and sync their changes back to GitHub. *sad sad*

Comment: The content is maintained by multiple companies and commenting on someone's workflow is quite difficult in my case. Very political topic.

Comment: Then pick one of the A, B and C you've already identified, because until and unless you can get someone in a position to fix the actual problem to do so, *that's your job* (or former job, in case C).

Comment: Generally, people around me always think they are cleverer and hack things if they could, "time is money." In short, they are not software developers, so they don't really care how things should work. Very target-oriented.

Comment: Right, but if they're generating the revenue and those targets are the business's targets, your job is to help not hinder them. If there's a good case to make that overall productivity (and therefore revenue!) would be higher if something changed, make that case to someone who can make it happen. But again, that's an organisational problem not a technical one.

Comment: Also, if your colleagues are continuously making edits to your files, rather than trying to stop them you'd probably be better served by giving them a better/easier way of doing what they're trying to do. Could you pull the relevant parts out into a configuration file, or something along those lines?

Comment: True, people issue.